# ORA-00904: "Q"."ITEM_NO": invalid identifier - Oracle SQL group by issue

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have this query to fetch item no's and their quantities filtered by a specific unit.

```
select q.item_no, sum(q.quantity) from item_unit_quantity q 
where q.unit_no = 'PH00000096' group by q.item_no
```

Now I want to add price column which I get from another two tables

**There is a condition, Price is always the maximum of the latest three GRN dates.**

```
select max(price) from (select price from grn_item gi join grn g on gi.grn_no = g.grn_no 
where gi.item_no = 'IT00001896' order by g.grn_date desc) where rownum <= 3
```

When I combined the queries as below,

```
select q.item_no, sum(q.quantity), 
(select max(price) from (select price from grn_item gi join grn g on gi.grn_no = g.grn_no 
where gi.item_no = q.item_no order by g.grn_date desc) where rownum <= 3) "PRICE"
from item_unit_quantity q where q.unit_no = 'PH00000096' group by q.item_no
```

I get

> ORA-00904: "Q"."ITEM_NO": invalid identifier

But if I change the above as "**gi.item_no = 'IT00001896'**" I get

```
ITEM_NO    | Sum(Quantity) | Price
--------------------------------------
IT00012824 | 14            | 3.68
IT00006345 | 494           | 3.68
IT00001896 | 5             | 3.68
```

I still want to display the Item no, Item quantity and **price for each Item no** in this query, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to follow without sample data.  However, subqueries with `GROUP BY` can be finicky.  A simple solution is to  move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
select q.item_no, sum(q.quantity), max(max_price)
from item_unit_quantity q left join
     (select gi.item_no, max(g.price) as max_price
      from grn_item gi join
           grn g
           on gi.grn_no = g.grn_no 
      group by gi.item_no
     ) gi
     on gi.item_no = q.item_no 
where q.unit_no = 'PH00000096'
group by q.item_no
```

Comment: thank you, u mean sample data of all the tables? and why is left join used in your answer? cant we use join instead?

Comment: @DilhanNakandala . . . `LEFT JOIN` is used to preserve rows in the first table if there are no matches.  If that is not needed, just use `JOIN`.  As for sample data, yes, for all tables -- and the results.  That is usually the clearest way to explain a question.